# Weblogic 10.3 deployment error

Tags: weblogic-10.x

This question is Not Answered.

aaa0336b-de3a-4ef2-8c45-e48b1de160cb Jul 1, 2013 8:33 PM

I am getting the following error while deploying an application in weblogic10.3

1. SEVERE: Failed to pre-compile WSDL files:  [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: admin

   at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl(ResponseImpl.java:237)
   at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
   at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
   at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_1036_WLStub(null:-1)
   at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl(WLContextImpl.java:424)

2.

I am getting the following error while deploying an application in weblogic10.3

SEVERE: Failed to pre-compile WSDL files:  [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: admin

```
at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl(ResponseImpl.java:237)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_1036_WLStub(null:-1)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl(WLContextImpl.java:424)
```